# ANTLR grammar license

Tags: licensing, lua, grammar, antlr3

I'm planning to make an implementation of Lua for the DLR, and i would like to use the listed Lua 5.1 grammar [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list). However i can't see a license that it was released under, so can someone please kindly point me in the direction of the license it uses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for the lexical parts, the grammar looks like it's [copied](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) from the Lua reference manual, which is subject to the MIT license.

Answer (score 2):

As it doesn't say (and a brief dig around the site doesn't indicate), the default state is that the copyright resides with the author. You'll have to contact him/her directly to use it legally.

Comment: I would tend to agree, but the ANTLR says that it's used in LunarEclipse, which is licensed under the Eclipse Public License.